# App crashes when trying to encode custom objects that conform to codable protocol and I can't figure out why, any thoughts?

Tags: swift, object, codable, jsonencoder

So I have two custom objects, Exercises and Workouts. Exercises conforms to Codable and is able to be encoded and decoded just fine using JSONEncoder. I have an array of Exercise objects that I archive. The issue is with the Workout object. For some reason it does not get encoded using the JSON encoder. I am trying to encode an object which contains two arrays of Workout objects.

Any thoughts as to why this is crashing? I earlier had the manual implementation of Codable in Workout object but it would crash at this line:

```
let exercisesData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: exercises, requiringSecureCoding: true)
```

Then I realized all attributes of Workout already conform to Codable so I commented it out. Code is below.

With the manual implementation of Codable in the Workout object removed, the error message I get is:

> The data couldn't be written because it isn't in the correct format

(again I'm using JSONEncoder to encode an object with 2 arrays of Workout objects).
If I leave the manual implementation uncommented, it crashes at this line:

```
let exercisesData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: exercises, requiringSecureCoding: true)
```

with the message:

> Exercise does not implement methodSignatureForSelector -- trouble ahead Unrecognized selector Exercise replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver

I'm new to Swift programming and I was following some guides on how to set this up. It has worked for me a few weeks ago with simpler data.

```
class Exercise: Equatable, Codable, NSCopying {
    var name: String
    var muscleGroup: String
    var description: String
    var image: UIImage
    var logs = [(weight: String, reps: String, complete: Bool)]()
    private let isPrimary: Bool
    
    //Init function
    init(name: String, muscleGroup: String, description: String, image: UIImage, isPrimary: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name //Treat this as unique
        self.muscleGroup = muscleGroup
        self.description = description
        self.image = image
        self.isPrimary = isPrimary
    }
    
    //Override equatable to check for uniqueness
    static func == (lhs: Exercise, rhs: Exercise) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name.lowercased() == rhs.name.lowercased()
    }
    
    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case muscleGroup
        case description
        case image
        case logs
        case isPrimary
    }
    
    //Decoder function implementation
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        // Decoding the name property
        let nameData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .name)
        self.name = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(nameData) as? String ?? "No Exercise Name"

        // Decoding the muscleGroup property
        let muscleGroupData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .muscleGroup)
        self.muscleGroup = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(muscleGroupData) as? String ?? "Other"

        // Decoding the description property
        let descriptionData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .description)
        self.description = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(descriptionData) as? String ?? "None"
        
        // Decoding the image property
        let imageData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .image)
        self.image = try (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(imageData) as? UIImage)!
        
        // Deocding the logs property
        let logsData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .logs)
        self.logs = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(logsData) as? [(weight: String, reps: String, complete: Bool)] ?? [(weight: String, reps: String, complete: Bool)]()
        
        // Deocding the primary property
        let isPrimaryData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .isPrimary)
        self.isPrimary = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(isPrimaryData) as? Bool ?? false
    }

    //Encoder function implementation
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        // Encoding the name property
        let nameData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: name, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        try container.encode(nameData, forKey: .name)

        // Encoding the muscleGroup property
        let muscleGroupData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: muscleGroup, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        try container.encode(muscleGroupData, forKey: .muscleGroup)

        // Encoding the description property
        let descriptionData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: description, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        try container.encode(descriptionData, forKey: .description)
        
        // Encoding the image property
        let imageData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: image, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        try container.encode(imageData, forKey: .image)
        
        // Encoding the logs property
        let logsData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: logs, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        try container.encode(logsData, forKey: .logs)
        
        // Encoding the primary property
        let isPrimaryData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: isPrimary, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        try container.encode(isPrimaryData, forKey: .isPrimary)
     }
}
```

```
class Workout: Codable {
    var title: String
    var date: Date
    let duration: String //in minutes
    var exercises = [Exercise]()
    private let isPrimary: Bool
    
    //Init function
    init(title: String, date: Date, duration: String, exercises: [Exercise], isPrimary: Bool = false) {
        self.title = title
        self.date = date
        self.duration = duration
        self.exercises = exercises
        self.isPrimary = isPrimary
    }
    
    // public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    //    case title
    //    case date
    //    case duration
    //    case exercises
    //    case isPrimary
    // }

    // //Decoder function implementation
    // required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    //     let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    //     // Decoding the title property
    //     let titleData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .title)
    //     self.title = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(titleData) as? String ?? "New Workout"

    //     // Decoding the date property
    //     let dateData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .date)
    //     self.date = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(dateData) as? Date ?? Date()

    //     // Decoding the duration property
    //     let durationData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .duration)
    //     self.duration = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(durationData) as? String ?? "0"

    //     //Decoding the exercises property
    //     let exercisesData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .exercises)
    //     self.exercises = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(exercisesData) as? [Exercise] ?? [Exercise]()

    //     // Deocding the primary property
    //     let isPrimaryData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .isPrimary)
    //     self.isPrimary = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(isPrimaryData) as? Bool ?? false
    // }

    // //Encoder function implementation
    // func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    //     var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    //     // Encoding the title property
    //     let titleData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: title, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    //     try container.encode(titleData, forKey: .title)

    //     // Encoding the date property
    //     let dateData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: date, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    //     try container.encode(dateData, forKey: .date)

    //     // Encoding the duration property
    //     let durationData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: duration, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    //     try container.encode(durationData, forKey: .duration)

    //     // Encoding the exercises property
    //     let exercisesData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: exercises, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    //     try container.encode(exercisesData, forKey: .exercises)

    //     // Encoding the primary property
    //     let isPrimaryData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: isPrimary, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    //     try container.encode(isPrimaryData, forKey: .isPrimary)
    // }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason at all to be using `NSKeyedArchiver` in your `encode` and no reason to use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` in your `init`. Just use the APIs provided by `Encoder` and `Decoder`.

Here's your code all cleaned up. I replaced the tuple being used for the logs with another struct. I changed your two classes to be struct. Only the `Exercise` struct needs a custom `init` and `encode` since `UIImage` doesn't conform to `Codable`. The only need for the custom `init` with all of the properties is to support default values for some of the properties.

Note that if a struct has properties that are all `Codable` then the whole struct is `Codable` without writing any code. Same for `Equatable`.

```
struct Log: Codable {
    let weight: String
    let reps: String
    let complete: Bool
}

struct Exercise: Equatable, Codable {
    let name: String
    let muscleGroup: String
    let description: String
    let image: UIImage
    let logs: [Log]
    let isPrimary: Bool

    init(name: String, muscleGroup: String, description: String, image: UIImage, logs: [Log] = [], isPrimary: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.muscleGroup = muscleGroup
        self.description = description
        self.image = image
        self.logs = logs
        self.isPrimary = isPrimary
    }

    //Override equatable to check for uniqueness
    static func == (lhs: Exercise, rhs: Exercise) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name.lowercased() == rhs.name.lowercased()
    }

    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case muscleGroup
        case description
        case image
        case logs
        case isPrimary
    }

    //Decoder function implementation
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        // Decoding the name property
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)

        // Decoding the muscleGroup property
        muscleGroup = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .muscleGroup)

        // Decoding the description property
        description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)

        // Decoding the image property
        let imageData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .image)
        image = UIImage(data: imageData)!

        // Deocding the logs property
        logs = try container.decode([Log].self, forKey: .logs)

        // Deocding the primary property
        isPrimary = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isPrimary)
    }

    //Encoder function implementation
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        // Encoding the name property
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)

        // Encoding the muscleGroup property
        try container.encode(muscleGroup, forKey: .muscleGroup)

        // Encoding the description property
        try container.encode(description, forKey: .description)

        // Encoding the image property
        let imageData = image.pngData()
        try container.encode(imageData, forKey: .image)

        // Encoding the logs property
        try container.encode(logs, forKey: .logs)

        // Encoding the primary property
        try container.encode(isPrimary, forKey: .isPrimary)
    }
}

struct Workout: Codable {
    let title: String
    let date: Date
    let duration: String //in minutes
    let exercises: [Exercise]
    let isPrimary: Bool

    init(title: String, date: Date, duration: String, exercises: [Exercise], isPrimary: Bool = false) {
        self.title = title
        self.date = date
        self.duration = duration
        self.exercises = exercises
        self.isPrimary = isPrimary
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, I don't need NSKeyedArchiver stuff, I'll give this a shot, thank you!

Comment: `NSKeyedArchiver` is not part of Swift. It's the old Foundation archival method from Objective-C. While you can use it in Swift, Swift provides much better and easier methods (via `Codable`).